# What could be different in https implementation for python vs nodejs?

Tags: python, node.js, http

I am trying to figure out one weird issue. I have working python code which I want to translate to NodeJS. Python code very simple and works:

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth'
params = {'Email': '***', 'EncryptedPasswd': b'***', 'service': 'androidmarket', 'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE', 'has_permission': 1, 'source': 'android', 'device_country': 'us', 'lang': 'us'}
response = requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data=params, verify=True)
print(response.text)
```

Here is NodeJS version code:

```
const request = require('request');

const LOGIN_URL = 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth'
const params = {'Email': '***', 'EncryptedPasswd': '***', 'service': 'androidmarket', 'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE', 'has_permission': 1, 'source': 'android', 'device_country': 'us', 'lang': 'us'}
request({url: LOGIN_URL, method: 'POST', form: params}, function(error, response) {
   console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

This does not work, I am getting back 403 - Bad request.
I have tried to change protocol to http and then check packets contents in Wireshark. They are pretty much same with minor differences. I tried eliminating all the differences by overriding headers in NodeJS version, it did not help. So my guess is something wrong with https?

What am I missing? What could be the difference between Python and NodeJS?

Comment: use url https://httpbin.org/post in both code and you get back (as JSON data) all hearders, cookies, etc. send to this url  - and then you can compare result from Python and NodeJS.

Comment: eventually use some local proxy server like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Man-In-The-Middle Proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)  (created in Python) and use them in both connections to see all data send to server - and then you can compare them.

Comment: you can also test url with [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) - and both have function to generate code in different languages - ie. `Python` and `NodeJS`

Comment: @furas I already tested HTTP requests contents via Wireshark and I was able to achieve identical content for both Python and NodeJS.

Comment: you can't get identical - `requests` sends header `"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.23.0"` and `NodeJS` for sure doesn't sends `"python-requests/2.23.0"`. You can have other differences.

Comment: @furas Sorry If I did not explain properly, I tried adjusting all the headers to be exactly same(Overriding user agent header in NodeJS version to "python-requests/2.23.0", seetting connection to "keep-alive" etc). In wireshark requests look identical.

Comment: at this moement I don't have project with Google API to test this problem but there is [Google API NodeJS](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) (similar to [Google API Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)) which can be more useful then normal manual request.

Comment: This is not related to official google API. I am trying to use unofficial google play store api. This library https://github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/PlaystoreDownloader works for me, but it is in Python. I can't replicate same functionality in NodeJS.

Comment: It shouldn’t make any difference but can you try using “request.post” instead of “request”?

Comment: @Aleksey In Python, you send the `EncryptedPasswd` in bytes (that's why you have there the b literal) and I don't see that you do that as well in the JS code.

Comment: @momo But it seems like this does not make any difference. When I see this in http request in wireshark these are identical because `EncryptedPasswd` sent as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Second guess:

Logins require cookies, NodeJS `requests` disables cookies by default. Try:

```js
const request = request.defaults({jar: true})
```

First guess:

Differences between the python code and the Node.js code as posted:

- The python code sends these headers:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
HTTP_USER_AGENT: python-requests/2.24.0
```

- The Node code sends only these headers:

```
HTTP_CONNECTION: close
```

Quite possibly the headers could be the problem, but also possible is that the Python code has access to a cookie jar and is adding cookies to the request the that the Node.JS code is not.

Another possibility is that your two clients are using two different TLS stacks (or at least 2 different configurations) and the NodeJS client is not able to negotiate an acceptable cypher.

I suggest you use a tool like Postman to manually try variants of requests to figure out which ones work and which ones do not. If you get it working in Postman, use Postman to export the code snippets for Python and NodeJS and confirm that they work. If the exported code works in Python but not NodeJS, then the problem is not the code.

Most likely the problem is something you are not aware of and therefore not telling us about. Have Postman export `curl` and `wget` commands, too, so you can verify that they work inside your Docker containers and that the issue is not with the container or Docker networking. Use `curl -v` to see what TLS cipher is being negotiated and configure NodeJS to only use that version of TLS and only that cipher, because Google likes to block clients that allow for downgrading to old broken TLS versions or weak ciphers.

Comment: I am sorry if I did not describe it clearly, but I did try changing NodeJS version to send exactly same data, including all the headers. I have checked sent requests in Wireshark and they look identical.

Comment: I have tried just tried Postman and it also works executing request from Postman. Then I used "Code" functionality. Exported request in NodeJS code, run it and I still get 403 - Bad request.

Comment: I tested code with all headers and even using different modules `https` and `fetch`, and my only idea is that problem is on lower level - ie. SSL/TLS

Comment: @Aleksey The login might do a redirect requiring cookies, but NodeJS disables cookies by default. I updated my answer.

Comment: @OldPro I tried this but did not work. Also tried to pass cookie jar explicitly with request, nothing changed. How can I verify that there is redirect going on?

Comment: @Aleksey Sorry, if there were a redirect you would have seen it when running Postman. Clearly there is something wrong with your NodeJS installation/configuration, but hard to say what. Probably something you are not aware of and therefore not telling us. Try doing a clean install of NodeJS Stable (currently 12.13.0) and running your code snippet with that.

Comment: Tried running same script from clean docker container, does not help.

Comment: @Aleksey If you have a working request in Postman that, when you export it using the Postman Code export, does not work in NodeJS, then the problem is likely not the request but your Nodejs setup. You could, however, double-check by exporting as "Nodejs - Native" rather than "Nodejs - Request". Other thing to check is that you can get the Python request working from the same Docker container that NodeJS is running in, to rule out Docker networking issues. While you are at it, export the request from Postman as `cURL` and verify that that works in all your environments.

Comment: @Aleksey, Is the `Content-Type` header value in python and nodejs same?

Comment: @VenkatakumarSrinivasan Yes it is  `x-www-form-urlencoded` in both cases

Comment: Then, a couple of things to double check: the request body is the same in both cases, and `b'***'` in python is a string and not a byte array.